# Can I do change in the size of JTextField using GridLayout (like width and height of field)?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager, grid-layout

can I do change in the size of `JTextField` using `GridLayout` (like width and height of field) in Java

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
txt=new JTextField(20);
```

Comment: `GridLayout` will resize all components to be the same size.  One way 'around' that is to put the (e.g.) text field in a `JPanel` with the default flow layout, then put the panel in the grid layout.  The panel will be stretched to fill, but the text field inside it will remain at its preferred size.  General tips:  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: I did it as you said it was good idea thank you so much

Comment: @AndrewThompson For posterity, could you write that up as an answer? Assuming this isn't a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

`GridLayout` will resize all components to be the same size.

One way 'around' that is to put the (e.g.) text field in a `JPanel` with the default flow layout, then put the panel in the grid layout. The *panel* will be stretched to fill, but the text field inside it will *remain at its preferred size.*